# Proving convexity of $f(K)=\ln\left(\frac{\sin(t\sqrt{K})}{\sin(\sqrt{K})}\right)$ for $K\in(0,\pi^2)$

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry, convex-analysis

Define for $K\in(0,\pi^2)$ the function
$$f:K\quad\mapsto\quad\ln\left(\frac{\sin(t\sqrt{K})}{\sin(\sqrt{K})}\right)\qquad t\in(0,1)\mbox{ fixed}.$$I need to prove convexity of this function as function of $K$ but how? As function of $K$, the second derivative is pretty terrifying.

Comment: Do you mean convexity in the derivative sense? Or in the sense of: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function? Either way just use the respective definitions. There will be cancellations in the derivative. Also: it is not obvious whether this is a function of one or two variables.

Comment: I tried the usual definition of convexity but I didn't get anywhere, so I tried the derivative characterization but I got lost (I'm reading a paper where the authors just say "it's convex")

P.s. I didn't checked for differentiability or something, just trying different things

Comment: Just use the derivative definition even if it is “pretty terrifying”. You can also use a software as an aid given that you know what you are doing.

Comment: Or you can separate the ln(ab)=ln(a)+ ln(b) or expand the ln(y) and maybe the sin(y) into a series or into their complex definitions etc..

Comment: Yeah I mean, with a calculator you can see clearly that for $K\in(0,\pi^2)$ the second derivative of the thing is greater than $0$, just wanted to check the convexity without the second derivative

Answer (score 0):

$$f(K)=\log \left(\csc \left(\sqrt{K}\right) \sin \left(\sqrt{K} t\right)\right)=\log \left(\csc \left(\sqrt{K}\right) \right)+\log \left(\sin \left(t\sqrt{K} \right)\right)$$
$$f''(K)=\frac{\sqrt{K} \left(\csc ^2\left(\sqrt{K}\right)-t^2 \csc ^2\left(t\sqrt{K}
   \right)\right)-t \cot \left(t\sqrt{K}\right)+\cot \left(\sqrt{K}\right)}{4
   K^{3/2}}$$
Expanding as a series around $t=0$ gives
$$f''(K)=\frac{\sqrt{K} \cot \left(\sqrt{K}\right)+K \csc ^2\left(\sqrt{K}\right)-2}{4
   K^2}-\frac{t^4}{90}+O\left(t^6\right)$$ It is quite simple to show that the first term is always positive.

Moreover, for small values of $K$

$$f''(K)=\frac{1}{90}+\frac{2 K}{945}+\frac{K^2}{3150}+\frac{4
   K^3}{93555}+O\left(K^{4}\right)$$ and for $K$ close to $\pi^2$
$$f''(x)=\frac{1}{\left(K-\pi ^2\right)^2}+\frac{4 \pi ^2-33}{48 \pi ^4}+\frac{\left(21-2 \pi
   ^2\right) \left(K-\pi ^2\right)}{16 \pi ^6}+O\left(\left(K-\pi
   ^2\right)^2\right)$$